# Length of a char array in C

Tags: c, string

I want to calculate the length of an char array in C with a while loop.
But If I insert `otto` it returns the length of `5`. Shouldn't be `4` the right answer?

```
char eingabe[255];

printf("geben Sie eine Zeile ein:");
fgets(eingabe, 255, stdin);

int i = 0;
while (eingabe[i] != '\0')
{
    ++i;
}

printf("Laenge: %d\n", i);
```

Comment: It's probably counting a new line character (`\n`). Read `man fgets`.

Comment: `fgets` retains the new-line character at the end of the line, so you get 4 for "otto" plus one for that.

Comment: Why do you re-implement strlen()?

Comment: Side note: when asking for help, have some consideration and write your code in English. It's not very important in this example, but with harder questions, it's a showstopper.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's very likely that `eingabe` contains:

```
{ 'o', 't', 't', 'o', '\n', '\0', junk ... }
```

Answer (score 7):

Check the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets) of `fgets()`.

> Reading stops after an EOF or a newline. If a newline is read, it is stored into the buffer.

As you are reading from `stdin`, it stores the trailing `newline` [`\n`] character also in the supplied buffer.

Change your check to `while ((eingabe[i] != '\0') && (eingabe[i] != '\n'))`. Hope this will solve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

A newline character `'\n'` makes `fgets` stop reading, but it is considered a valid character by the function, and included in the string copied to the result. If you would like to avoid this, use `fscanf` like this:

```
fscanf(stdin, "%254[^\n]", eingabe);
```

Note the limit in the format: it is less than the actual length of the buffer to accommodate the null terminator.

Note: You can use `strlen` to compute the length of the string. It does the same thing as your `for` loop:

```
int i = strlen(eingabe);
```

Answer (score 0):

The size of `eingabe` is 255.  Now, if you want the number of initialized characters in it you should use `strlen`.  But first, insert this code:

```
int n;
for(n = 0; n < 255; n++){
  if(eingabe[n] == '\n'){
    eingabe[n] = '\0';
  }
}
eingabe[254] = '\0';
```

This code replaces the '\n' character with a NULL character.  Without this, `strlen` will return wrong values.  I also include `eingabe[254] = '\0';` so that if the string read in is long enough that the newline character does not fit in the buffer, there is still a NULL character so that strlen can function properly